# Can not use Count() on property of Collection linQ

Tags: linq, collections, count

I am trying to take the first top 5 products have been sold. My idea is I counted the total of product ID which is uniqu, but I got the error showing that:

> 'int?' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension
> method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'int?'

I have tried many ways around 2 hours but still, couldn't find the right way to handle it.
this is my snippet code:

```
using(var ctx = new AuctionSiteDBEntities())
            {
                var listget = (from q in ctx.Auctions
                orderby q.IDPro.Count() descending
                select q).Take(5);
            }
```

Comment: `q.IDPro` is, apparently, an `int?`. What are you counting here?

Comment: Do you have a navigation property to the product table?

Answer (score 0):

I find LINQ query syntax more understandable for grouping:

```
var listget = (from q in ctx.Auctions
               group q by q.IDPro into qg
               orderby qg.Count() descending
               select qg.First()).Take(5);
```